# Setting height of a rect by form input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to make something where you can manually fill in the height of a rect with a form.

So this means: if I change the amount of the first form imput to 10, then the first rect must have height=10.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var height = -Math.random()*450;
        ctx.fillStyle = "#76DCDC";
        ctx.fillRect(16+i*100,400,60,height);
}
```

With this code I generate a random height every time I press the submit button. 
But I need the code to fill the height in manually for each of the 5 different rectangles.

This is what I have so far. But it's still very messy.

```js
 var amount = [];
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 
 if(canvas.getContext){ 
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var hoeveelheid = 0;
 

  var emmer = new Image();
  emmer.addEventListener("load",drawDrop );
  emmer.src = "assets/pot_s.png";
 }else{
 }

 
 function draw(){
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FFF';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
 }

 
 function amountChange(){
  console.log("change amount");
  var form = document.getElementById("form");

  for(var i = 0; i < form.length; i++){
   amount[i] = form[i].value;
  }
  draw();
 }

 
 function drawDrop() {
 ctx.fillStyle="#FFF"
 ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     var height = -Math.random()*450;
  ctx.fillStyle = "#76DCDC";
  ctx.fillRect(17+i*100,410,60,height);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   ctx.drawImage(emmer,i*100,400);
  }

  hoeveelheid ++;
  if (hoeveelheid == 8) {
   hoeveelheid = 1;
  }
 }


 function randomize(){
  console.log("random amount");

  var form = document.getElementById("form");

  for(var i = 0; i < form.length; i++){
   form[i].value = Math.round(Math.random()*25)*5;
  }

  amountChange();
 }


 function calculate() {
  console.log("bereken gegevens");
  
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>CPII</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen.css">
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
 <div>
  <h1>Watergebruik</h1>
  <p>Hoeveel minuten heb je vandaag ... gebruikt?</p>

  <form id="form" method="post">

  De wc: <input type="number" name="wc" step="5" min="0" max="255"><br>
  De douche: <input type="number" name="douche" step="5"  min="0" max="255" ><br>
  De lavabo: <input type="number" name="lavabo" step="5"  min="0" max="255" ><br>
  De keukenkraan: <input type="number" name="keukenkraan" step="5"  min="0" max="255"><br>
  De wasmachine: <input type="number" name="wasmachine" step="5"  min="0" max="255"><br>
  De vaatwas: <input type="number" name="vaatwas" step="5"  min="0" max="255"><br>

  <button onclick="calculate()">See the results</button>
  <button onclick="randomize()">Random numbers</button>

  </form>
 </div>
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your whole code...or a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the value of the form inputs.
I'm using jquery here for a quick example.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 var height = document.getElementById('#input' + i).value;
 ctx.fillStyle = "#76DCDC";
 ctx.fillRect(16+i*100,400,60,height);
}
```

This works for all 4 inputs. The IDs of the inputs must be "input1" - "input4"

Comment: Thank you very much! But is there also a way to do this without jQuery ?